# Count items of list parameter

Tags: c#, list, linq, count

I have this:

```
public int Control_list(List<int> items)
```

And I want to count the items in the list using LINQ and if the list is null, then return 0

I hav tried this, but it does not pass all scenarios of what could be in items

```
bool isEmpty = !items.Any();
if (isEmpty)
{
    return items.Count;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What scenarios is it not passing?

Comment: Well I get an error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `Any` won't work if the object is null. You need to do the null check first. After that, calling `Any` is superfluous, because `Count` will return 0 if `Any` is false anyway.

So, just use

```
public int Control_list(List<int> items)
{
    if (items == null) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return items.Count;
    }
}
```

Or (using the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to make it shorter):

```
public int Control_list(List<int> items)
{
    return items == null ? 0 : items.Count;
}
```

Comment: This worked but was not how I wanted to do it. Do you mind explaining a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Ok thank you for the edit, breaking it out makes it easier for me to understand. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Or just `return items?.Count ?? 0;`.  The [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx) returns null if the previous `items` is null (thus `Count` property would never be executed) then i used the  [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) which states if the value on the left is null, then return the value on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Some Style Input: Insteed of list you can also pass in ilist or ienumerable ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your condition should be if (!isEmpty ).

If you insist on using linq .Any(), check for null first:

```
public int Control_list(List<int> items)
{
    bool isEmpty = items != null ? !items.Any() : true;

    if (!isEmpty )
    {
        return items.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will never work. Default only kicks in if you don't provide the parameter at all. And the default for any reference type is null.